# Prefix for last name: "in der"

Tags: person-names

While watching TV, I noticed that a person interviewed was named *In der Maur*. Rarely you can read *von* as prefix, mostly by former nobles, but it's the first time I have read *in der* as a prefix. I would assume that this is some *very* old German variant like *Mittelhochdeutsch* or earlier.

Is it even a German name?

Where does this name come from? From what time or period might this name be? And is it known what kind of people got such a prefix?

*Note: I understand that this question might not be the perfect fit for German.SE, but looking at Genealogy.SE, it would be a worse fit there. I also found the `person-name` tag here with 68 questions, so I assume it's ok to ask.*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_der_Maur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to forebears.io, there are 450 "In der Maur" in Switzerland, as well as 350 "Indermaur" in Austria,

Wikipedia says that the name "In der Maur" comes from a old noble Swiss family from the 15th century. Apparently, there's also a branch of the family in Austria, which totally explains the numbers above.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_der_Maur

https://forebears.io/surnames/in_der_maur

https://forebears.io/surnames/indermaur

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Just a note: On forebears.io i can not find those mentioned 350 members in Austria. Am I looking at the wrong source? I can see 1 and 0 for those links above.

Comment: Whoops... 
There are 450 "Indermaur" worldwide, including 350 in Switzerland. That's what I meant.
Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: No  worries. There's always  the possibility to fix things with an [edit] :)